# data fetching from mysql using php and angular not working in some mobile device whereas it is working on desktop, laptop

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, mysqli

data fetch from `mysql` is not working in mobile whereas it is working in desktop and laptop. 
This is HTML Code in html file:

```
<table class="table table-default">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>R</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>R/S Out</th>
        <th>Pts</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="myteam in teamperformance">
        <td>{{myteam.team}}</td>
        <td>{{myteam.runs}}</td>
        <td>{{myteam.wickets}}</td>
        <td>{{myteam.run_out}}</td>
        <td>{{myteam.catces}}</td>
        <td>{{myteam.points}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this script code

```
<script>
  $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'api/myteamPerformance.php'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // Store response data
    $scope.teamperformance = response.data;
  });
</script>
```

And bellow is myteamPerformance.php

```
<?php 
 include 'api/data_config.php';
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
 $qry = "SELECT * 
FROM c_batsmen, c_myteam
WHERE c_batsmen.batsmen=c_myteam.team COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
AND c_batsmen.match_id=c_myteam.match_id COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
AND c_myteam.user_id=$user_id";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry)
or die("Error:".mysqli_error($conn));
 $data = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $data[] = array("team"=>$row['batsmen'],"runs"=>$row['runs'],"wickets"=>$row['wickets'],"catches"=>$row['catches'],"run_out"=>$row['run_out'],"matchid"=>$row['match_id'],"contestid"=>$row['contest_id']);
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

This code is working in desktop but on mobile data is not showing.

Comment: "not working" is not a helpfull error description

Comment: Stack overflow is not a debugging service. Take the [tour], read [ask]. And add details around what your actual problem is, include a copy of the actual error message you got, and explain what you already searched/tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using `route` in your application, i suggest it's cache problem, your browser on desktop has `ctrl + F5` to **hard refresh** for reload all data and files but your mobile device doesn't have this option.

*you didn't have any error and not related to your `mysql` and how to request data.*

**solution**

Try to version your **requests** and **files**, example:

```
var version = "0.0.1";
$http({
method: 'get',
url: 'api/myteamPerformance.php?v=' + version
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
});
```

use this version for (Html and js) files too as `'view.html?v='+version` or  `'controller.js?v='+version`.

> Version helps users devices (mobile, desktop, ...) to get last version of your application.

Comment: Thank you very much Maher, great solution, problem resolved.